# Copy formula from top to bottom

Tags: excel, vba

I insert a formula in column "G2",and want to populate down wherever The dataset stop, my problem is the only column without space is "B", so I write this code, it stops at "ActiveSheet.Paste"

Any help will be welcome

```
'Add True False column
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "True/False"
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ISNUMBER(RC[-1])"
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

try  `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).copy` instead of Select

and `Activecell.Paste` instead of `ActiveSheet.Paste`

Comment: I try both the macro stop at "ActiveCell.Paste"

Comment: What is "stop"?

Comment: the macro run part to the code and stop at line   "ActiveCell.Paste"